# How do I stop my System.Messaging.MessageQueue from wrapping my strings in XML?

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, msmq

I need to communicate with a legacy application from my C# app via the Windows Message Queue.

The legacy application expects plain string messages in a particular private queue, but I can't seem to stop the System.Messaging.MessageQueue from wrapping my message in XML!

The code I'm testing is very simple:

```
MessageQueue myQueue = new MessageQueue(@".\Private$\tolegacy");
Message msg = new Message("My Test String");
myQueue.Send(msg);
```

The trouble is that the message is being XML serialized and appears in the queue as:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><string>My Test String</string>
```

**I can't modify the behaviour of the legacy application, so I need to stop the System.Messaging.MessageQueue from formatting my message as XML.**

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own formatter (it is a class that implements IMessageFormatter and assign it to the Formatter property of the Message

Here is a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.message.formatter.aspx) to MSDN to the Message.Formatter property.

I have not tried this but you should be able to write your message using the BodyStream, I believe this will bypass the formatter.

Comment: Writing directly to the BodyStream worked, thanks.  It looked like the easiest change so I tried it first :)

Comment: I've written several myself and they work really well. The only thing you have to worry about is the sender and reciever understanding the body type.

Comment: We are having similar issue.  We can read/write queue and get message back fine.  But when vendor reads queue, he sees the extra "stuff" wrapped around our message.  How can we just write a simple string with no wrapping at all?  Even BinaryFormatter added a bunch of bytes at the beginning of the string.

Comment: Answer was - remove all formatters - 
MemoryStream myStream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(myString);
msg.BodyStream = myStream; 
Q.Send(msg);

Comment: To correct a few bugs in @NealWalters's above comment, it's `using System.Text;` then `var memStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(myString));` then `var msg = new Message { BodyStream = memStream };` then `Q.Send(msg);`

Answer (score 4):

Using the [ActiveXMessageFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.activexmessageformatter.aspx) will give you the desired result. We had the same issue with just wanting to pass a string to a queue and have the listener process read in the body as a string. The **ActiveXMessageFormatter** is used for serializing/deserializing primitive data types and will not put an XML wrapper on your input as is the case with the default **XmlMessageFormatter**.

```
mq.Formatter = new ActiveXMessageFormatter();
```

[Here](http://msinnovations.wordpress.com/2008/05/22/activexmessageformatter-rocks/) is another link describing the 3 different formatters as well.